# React + Redux : Why is this causing infinite render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, rendering, infinite-loop

I have 3 components. A Root, Child1 and Child2. **All 3 of the redux connected components. And each one of the has a useState to fetch required data on the initial render.**

Root includes an object to map childs. It decides which to render based on clicked button.

```
const [child, setChild] = useState('')
```

and hashmap is

```
const childs= { 
   c1 : Child1,
   c2 : Child2
}
```

in Root's render I have this;

```
<button onClick={() => setChild('c1')}>Show child1</button>
<button onClick={() => setChild('c2')}>Show child2</button>
...
{child ? <RenderChild /> : </>}
```

where `RenderChild` is like below;

```
const RenderChild = () => {
   const Tag = childs[child]
   return <Tag />
}
```

If I go like this. Then an infinite render loop triggered. I see the same network request that is initiated by selected child component and app goes unresponsive state. Browser tab freezes etc..

If I comment out the useState in the child to not to update the redux store. Then infinite render not happening but obviously the app is not working as expected too :)

If I call `RenderChild` just like a regular function in render, no infinite render loop created and problem solved.

```
...
{child ? RenderChild() : </>}
...
```

My thory is;
Since I call  like this an outside render triggered (sorry for breaking the terminology). Which in updates the store and it re-renders the root. Since root's state is something to render either one of the childs  called again and as one might see the loop created. But if I call RenderChild() as a function then first javascript evaluates my expression and puts my child there. Then the render begin and so the loop is not created.

Is this correct ? or what is the reason behind this behavioral madness generated by **me** ?

---

the component I gave some snippets is below. **This component keeps re-rendering. Childs updating the store and another render triggered.**

```
export interface ICustomerDetailProps extends StateProps, DispatchProps, RouteComponentProps<{ id: string }> {}

export const CustomerDetail = (props: ICustomerDetailProps) => {
  const [componentName, setComponentName] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    props.getEntity(props.match.params.id);
  }, []);

  const { customerEntity } = props;

  const components = {
    releaseList: CustomerReleases,
    ddsList: CustomerDDSList,
  };

  const RenderComponent = () => {
    const Tag = components[componentName];

    return <Tag id={props.match.params.id} />;
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Row>
        <Col md="8">
          <h2>
            {/* Customer [<b>{customerEntity.name}</b>] */}
            <b>{customerEntity.name}</b>
          </h2>
          <dl className="jh-entity-details">
            <dt>
              <span id="number">Number</span>
            </dt>
            <dd>{customerEntity.number}</dd>
            <dt>
              <span id="userName">User Name</span>
            </dt>
            <dd>{customerEntity.userName}</dd>
            <dt>Unit</dt>
            <dd>{customerEntity.unit ? customerEntity.unit.name : ''}</dd>
            <dt>Country</dt>
            <dd>{customerEntity.country ? customerEntity.country.name : ''}</dd>
          </dl>
          <Button tag={Link} to="/customer" replace color="info">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon="arrow-left" /> <span className="d-none d-md-inline">Back</span>
          </Button>
          &nbsp;
          <Button tag={Link} to={`/customer/${customerEntity.id}/edit`} replace color="primary">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon="pencil-alt" /> <span className="d-none d-md-inline">Edit</span>
          </Button>
          &nbsp;
          <Button disabled={false} onClick={() => setComponentName(componentName && componentName === 'releaseList' ? '' : 'releaseList')}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon="eye" /> <span className="d-none d-md-inline">Products</span>
          </Button>
          &nbsp;
          <Button disabled={false} onClick={() => setComponentName(componentName && componentName === 'ddsList' ? '' : 'ddsList')}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon="eye" /> <span className="d-none d-md-inline">List</span>
          </Button>
        </Col>
      </Row>

      <Row className="voffset-15">{componentName ? <RenderComponent /> : <></>}</Row>
    </>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ customer }: IRootState) => {
  return { customerEntity: customer.entity };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = { getEntity };

type StateProps = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps>;
type DispatchProps = typeof mapDispatchToProps;

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CustomerDetail);
```

---

**If I change the component to below then there is no re-render loop and it works.**

```
export interface ICustomerDetailProps extends StateProps, DispatchProps, RouteComponentProps<{ id: string }> {}

export const CustomerDetail = (props: ICustomerDetailProps) => {
  const [componentName, setComponentName] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    props.getEntity(props.match.params.id);
  }, []);

  const { customerEntity } = props;

  const components = {
    releaseList: CustomerReleases,
    ddsList: CustomerDDSList,
  };

  const renderComponent = () => {
    const Tag = components[componentName];

    return <Tag id={props.match.params.id} />;
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Row>
        <Col md="8">
          <h2>
            {/* Customer [<b>{customerEntity.name}</b>] */}
            <b>{customerEntity.name}</b>
          </h2>
          <dl className="jh-entity-details">
            <dt>
              <span id="number">Number</span>
            </dt>
            <dd>{customerEntity.number}</dd>
            <dt>
              <span id="userName">User Name</span>
            </dt>
            <dd>{customerEntity.userName}</dd>
            <dt>Unit</dt>
            <dd>{customerEntity.unit ? customerEntity.unit.name : ''}</dd>
            <dt>Country</dt>
            <dd>{customerEntity.country ? customerEntity.country.name : ''}</dd>
          </dl>
          <Button tag={Link} to="/customer" replace color="info">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon="arrow-left" /> <span className="d-none d-md-inline">Back</span>
          </Button>
          &nbsp;
          <Button tag={Link} to={`/customer/${customerEntity.id}/edit`} replace color="primary">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon="pencil-alt" /> <span className="d-none d-md-inline">Edit</span>
          </Button>
          &nbsp;
          <Button disabled={false} onClick={() => setComponentName(componentName && componentName === 'releaseList' ? '' : 'releaseList')}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon="eye" /> <span className="d-none d-md-inline">Products</span>
          </Button>
          &nbsp;
          <Button disabled={false} onClick={() => setComponentName(componentName && componentName === 'ddsList' ? '' : 'ddsList')}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon="eye" /> <span className="d-none d-md-inline">List</span>
          </Button>
        </Col>
      </Row>

      <Row className="voffset-15">{componentName ? renderComponent() : <></>}</Row>
    </>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ customer }: IRootState) => {
  return { customerEntity: customer.entity };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = { getEntity };

type StateProps = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps>;
type DispatchProps = typeof mapDispatchToProps;

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CustomerDetail);
```

Basically, my aim is to be able render child dynamically using state that button clicks triggers. As you can see I have to pass a prop to the child as well.

Comment: Why not pass `child` as prop to `RenderChild` instead of having it in closure and recreate the definition of the component every time Root renders? At least that is what I assume or else the couple of lines of code provided in your question would error out with `Uncaught ReferenceError: child is not defined`

Comment: thx but there is no error thrown with the code. it builds and works but keeps re-rendering. While you are saying pass it as props; something like `<RenderChild child={childs[child]} />`

Comment: @HMR updated the question to include full code related to page renders all these stuff.

Comment: I think I figured out the issue. Since I am creating the RenderComponent in the Root component these anomalies arises. Moved RenderComponent  out of the CustomerDetail component and now I can go with <RenderComponent .../>

Comment: @OlgunKaya yes, when you define a component like `RenderComponent` inside of another component it will get re-created on every render and unmounted and then remounted rather than just refreshing props.